# Costs of Amazon EC2 Large instance with instance-store

Tags: amazon-ec2, billing

I am not sure I understand the prices for EC2 instances.

Amazon writes:

> Pricing is per instance-hour consumed for each instance, from the time an instance is launched until it is terminated.

So I will get billed for 100% a month, unless I terminate this instance completely and lose all the data on the instance-store? This confuses me, as the Amazon cloud is said to be a cheaper alternative. But for a Large instance I end up with about $250/month, which is quite expensive compared to other, non-cloud companies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will be billed **24 instance-hours** per day if your instance (server) is online 24/7.

This is exactly the same as [Windows Azure](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/offers/) Web instances.

The **be billed just for what I use**, it's more about Files and Database, as the server should be always up and running.

If you compare VPS hosting companies with this prices, you will see Amazon/Windows are cheaper, keep in mind that you will have remote access to that server no matter what OS you are using (windows or Linux distro).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that. It seems I misunderstood what EC2 can do for me. I can get a dedicated server with about the same specs as a Large instance for about $60/month, including traffic.

Comment: Keep in mind that a dedicated server is not the same as a cloud server... you can't add instances of the same server in a dedicated hosting. **Plus**, there are plenty other hosting companies offering cloud computing, such as **Rackspace** (http://www.rackspace.com/cloud/cloud_hosting_products/servers/pricing/) and **Heroku** (http://www.heroku.com/pricing)

Answer (score 0):

You can stop your instance can keep it's volumes.  In that case you pay only for the storage while the instance is not running.

Comment: With instance-store there is no "stop" option.